# How to remove a image from files array in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am new to typescript,Here I need to remove a specific image from the selected image files array before post it to API.

app.component.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let url of urls;let i=index">
        <mat-card class="col-sm-12 mt-2" style="padding:4px">
            <div style="display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;">
                <img [src]="url" class="img-responsive img1" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-top:10px">
                <button class="col-sm-12" (click)="removeImage(i)" mat-raised-button color="primary">Remove</button>
            </div>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.components.ts

```
    onSelectFile(event) {
      this.urls = [];
      this.files= event.target.files;  // storing all the images files to the files variable

    if (this.files) {
          this.showImageBox = true;
          for (let file of this.files) {
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (e: any) => {
              this.urls.push(e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          }
        }
    }

removeImage(i){
//Here in this method how can I remove the specific image from the files array.
}
```

By using urls array I am displaying all the selected image to the user .Each image has remove button near it .When user clicks the remove button of an image I want to remove it from the files array before POST it to the API.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
removeImage(i){
 this.urls.splice(i, 1);
}
```

Comment: I want to remove the image from files array not from urls @RameezRaja

Comment: removeImage(i) => i here is the index of this.files array or this.urls array ?

Comment: Bro,that's urls index position but I want to remove the image from files array @RameezRaja

Comment: JS:
this.urls.push({ url: e.target.result, file_ref: file}); 

removeImage(i, file){
 this.urls.splice(i, 1);
 this.files.splice(this.files.indexOf(file), 1);
}

html:
(click)="removeImage(i, url.file_ref)"